# Why are all rows selected in MSFlexGrid when I select the last row?

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

I have an MSFlexGrid control with 2 columns and all of my data is displayed on this grid. When I click on the Add button, I add a new row, and I select my new row.

The problem is that all the rows get selected and I need to select only my new row.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Add_Click()
    FGrid.Rows = FGrid.Rows + 1
    FGrid.RowSel = FGrid.Rows - 1
    FGrid.ColSel = 0

    If FGrid.Rows > 1 Then ' > 10
        FGrid.TopRow = FGrid.Rows - 1
    Else
        FGrid.TopRow = 1 
    End If

    FGrid.TextMatrix(FGrid.RowSel, 0) = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    FGrid.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're looking for the `Row` property, instead of `RowSel`. *You can use a combination of the two though depending on your requirements*.

**`Row` Property:**

> Returns/sets the active cell in a FlexGrid.

**`RowSel` property:**

> Determines the starting or ending row or column for a range of cells.

When you set the `RowSel` value it's treated as the ending of the selection because the `Row` value is still 0 *(unchanged)*. Therefore, you need to use something like this:

```
FGrid.Row = FGrid.Rows - 1
'FGrid.RowSel = FGrid.Rows - 1   ' Optional.
```

One more thing, instead of incrementing `.Rows` and then using `TextMatrix()` to assign a value to the cell, you can use `AddItem` to add a row with a value in its first cell. In this case, your code would look something like this:

```
FGrid.AddItem Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")

FGrid.Row = FGrid.Rows - 1
'FGrid.RowSel = FGrid.Rows - 1   ' Optional.
FGrid.ColSel = 0

If FGrid.Rows > 10 Then
    FGrid.TopRow = FGrid.Rows - 1
End If

FGrid.SetFocus
```